# Speed up query where results with count(*) = 0 are included

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, group-by, query-optimization

I have a table `squitters` with, amongst others, a column `parsed_time`. I want to know the number of records per hour for the last two days and used this query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', parsed_time) AS hour , count(*) 
FROM squitters 
WHERE parsed_time > date_trunc('hour', now()) - interval '2 day' 
GROUP BY hour 
ORDER BY hour DESC;
```

This works, but hours with zero records do not appear in the result. I want to have hours 
with zero records also in the result with a count equal to zero, so I wrote this query using the `generate_series` function:

```
SELECT bins.hour, count(squitters.parsed_time)
FROM generate_series(date_trunc('hour', now() - interval '2 day'),  now(), '1 hour') bins(hour)
LEFT OUTER JOIN squitters ON bins.hour = date_trunc('hours', squitters.parsed_time) 
GROUP BY bins.hour
ORDER BY bins.hour DESC;
```

This works, in the results are hour-bins with counts equal to zero, but is considerably slower.

How can I have the speed of the first query with the count=zero results of the second query?

(btw. there is an index on `parsed_time`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and change the join condition so no date function is applied on column `parsed_time`:

```
SELECT b.hour, COUNT(s.parsed_time) cnt
FROM generate_series(date_trunc('hour', now() - interval '2 day'),  now(), '1 hour') b(hour)
LEFT OUTER JOIN squitters s
    ON  s.parsed_time >= b.hour
    AND s.parsed_time <  b.hours + interval '1 hour'
GROUP BY b.hour
ORDER BY b.hour DESC;
```

Alternatively, you could also try using a correlated subquery (or a lateral join) instead of a `left join` - this avoids the need for outer aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    b.hour,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM squitters s 
        WHERE s.parsed_time >= b.hour AND s.parsed_time <  b.hours + interval '1 hour'
    ) cnt
FROM generate_series(date_trunc('hour', now() - interval '2 day'),  now(), '1 hour') b(hour)
ORDER BY b.hour desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of [Common Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) to divide your problem into small chunks:

```
WITH cte AS (
    --First query your table
    SELECT date_trunc('hour', parsed_time) AS sq_hour , count(*) 
    FROM squitters 
    WHERE parsed_time > date_trunc('hour', now()) - interval '2 day' 
    GROUP BY hour 
    ORDER BY hour DESC
), series AS (
    --Create the series without the data returned from 1st query
    SELECT 
        bins.series_hour, 
        0
    FROM 
        generate_series(date_trunc('hour', now() - interval '2 day'),  now(), '1 hour') bins(series_hour) 
    WHERE 
        series_hour not in (SELECT sq_hour FROM cte)
)
--Union the result
SELECT * FROM cte 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM series 
ORDER BY 1
```